# Different citation styles for multilingual bibliography using biblatex-gost package

Tags: biblatex, citing

I am using `biblatex-gost` package, style `gost-authoryear`. Since I have a multilingual bibliography, I need the citations look differently depending on the language of a particular bibliography item.

As you can see at the example below, the citations of the articles with three authors, regardless the language of the articles, have the same structure, i.e. `Author 1 [и др.]`. What I need is that for items in Russian the abbreviation to stay и `др.`, whereas for items in English I need it to change to `et al.` Moreover, I would like to get rid of square brackets. In other words the citations should look like this: `Reverberi et al., 2012` and `Лисанюк и др., 2015`.

[image]

Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{cmap}               
\usepackage{mathtext}           
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}       
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel} 
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\frenchspacing
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,sorting=nyt,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=999,style=gost-authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{GOST.bib}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\begin{document}

Preserved defective offending he daughters on or (\cite{reverberi2012deduction}). Rejoiced prospect yet material servants out answered men admitted. Sportsmen certainty prevailed suspected am as (\cite{lisanyuketal}). Add stairs admire all answer the nearer yet length. Advantages prosperous remarkably my inhabiting so reasonably be if. Too any appearance announcing impossible one. Out mrs means heart ham tears shall power every.

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

and the `bib.` file

```
@article{reverberi2012deduction,
    title={Deduction without awareness},
    author={Reverberi, Carlo and Pischedda, Doris and Burigo, Michele},
    journal={Acta psychologica},
    volume={139},
    number={1},
    pages={244--253},
    year={2012},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{lisanyuketal,
    title={From the neuron doctrine to neural networks},
    author={Лисанюк, Елена Николаевна and Грфцова, Ирина Николаевна and Мигунов, Анатолий Иванович},
    journal={Журнал по аргументации},
    volume={16},
    number={8},
    pages={487--497},
    year={2015}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the example below. You need the options `language=auto` so that the language is switched also for citations, `autolang=other` so that it uses a (here, babel) language environment to do the language switching and then you need to specify the language of the entries which don't match the default document language, here adding `langid={english}` to the appropriate entry. You can use `language=autocite` if you only want language switching for citations but a completely Russian bibliography:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{reverberi2012deduction,
    langid = {english},
    title={Deduction without awareness},
    author={Reverberi, Carlo and Pischedda, Doris and Burigo, Michele},
    journal={Acta psychologica},
    volume={139},
    number={1},
    pages={244--253},
    year={2012},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{lisanyuketal,
    title={From the neuron doctrine to neural networks},
    author={Лисанюк, Елена Николаевна and Грфцова, Ирина Николаевна and Мигунов, Анатолий Иванович},
    journal={Журнал по аргументации},
    volume={16},
    number={8},
    pages={487--497},
    year={2015}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{cmap}               
\usepackage{mathtext}           
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}       
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel} 
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\frenchspacing
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,sorting=nyt,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=999,style=gost-authoryear,language=auto,autolang=other]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test3.bib}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
    and
    test \ifmorenames
  }
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
       {\finalandcomma}
       {}%
     \andothersdelim\bibstring{andothers}}
    {}}

\begin{document}

Preserved defective offending he daughters on or (\cite{reverberi2012deduction}). Rejoiced prospect yet material servants out answered men admitted. Sportsmen certainty prevailed suspected am as (\cite{lisanyuketal}). Add stairs admire all answer the nearer yet length. Advantages prosperous remarkably my inhabiting so reasonably be if. Too any appearance announcing impossible one. Out mrs means heart ham tears shall power every.

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason inclusion of `langid=english` field doesn't work for me when it is the last field in bibentry, but works when it is the first.

Comment: Can you give a MWE?